# Programmatically generate Django models for legacy databases

Tags: python, django, database

I'm trying to find out if there is a way to programmatically generate Django models for legacy databases. So given a list of legacy tables, create a model for each one. Here is an example of what I mean

```
class Person_001(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    huge_dataset = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    class Meta:
       managed = False
       db_table = 'person_001'
```

So for example, create this model for `person_001`, `person_002` etc...

I realize there may be a more efficient way of storing this data and I am opened to suggestions, but the data has been stored this way because `huge_dataset` is, well, huge.

Answer (score 1):

I think the documentation will help you tremendously here [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/legacy-databases/#howto-legacy-databases)

from the docs --
Auto-generate the models¶

Django comes with a utility called inspectdb that can create models by introspecting an existing database. You can view the output by running this command:

```
$ python manage.py inspectdb
```

Save this as a file by using standard Unix output redirection:

```
$ python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```